# Any way to prevent .NET's WebBrowser's from executing javascript?

Tags: c#, .net

I just don't want my WebBrowser to execute javascript at all. I don't need it for what I'm doing and causes errors. Is there any way to preventing from executing it? I tried setting the InnerHtml for all "SCRIPT" elements to an empty string but I get errors.

If I can find a way to capture all mouse events and keep the browser from getting them, that would do it. The only scripts that I really need to suppress are the ones generated by mouse interaction. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you provide more information - such as the errors that you are getting.

Comment: FYI, the WebBrowser controls (there are at least two of them) is not part of C#. It's part of .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET control does not have any properties, as far as I remember, to disable Javascript. The only way to change it is through Internet Explorer security settings. I do not recommend doing that programatically.